# NDepend code rule needed for detecting Async constructions inside sync method lacking exception handling

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, ndepend

An interesting rule would be to detect async's without exception handling. Consider the following example where you need to run some async code inside a sync method:

```
public void SomeSyncMethod()
{

   Task.Run(async () =>
   {
       //Do something
   }

}
```

The problem with this construction is exceptions are swallowed into a black hole if unhandled. Is it possible to define a rule for this?